# Passing variables in yaml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

I love using i18n and yml. I want my own yaml file that do similar thing. That is accessing variable in yaml file. Something like this

```
name:
  address: "%{city} %{street}"
```

add variable could pass something like `some_method('name.address', :city => 'my city', :street => 'my street')`

In i18n we can do

```
en:
 message:
  welcome: "Hello %{username}"
```

To call this we can use `t("message.welcome", :username => 'admin')`

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's replace after the call. By example.

```
Yaml.load_file('locale/en.yml')['en']['message']['welcome'].gsub('%{username}', username)
```

So in method it can be :

```
  def t(key, changes)
    result = yaml_locale['en']
    key.split('.').each |k|
      result = result[k]
    end
    changes.each_keys do |k|
      result.gsub!("%{#{k}}%", changes[k])
    end
    result
  end
```

Refactor it a little after but the idea is like that.

The original method is here : https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n.rb#L143 Manage a lot of think I don't :)